# How to check if a bytes32 represents an empty string?

Tags: solidity, testing, bytes32

Why does the `require` not throw here when I am passing an empty string for the `_name` param?

```
function MyContract(bytes32 _name) public {
        require(_name.length > 0);
        name = _name;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bytes32 type is always exactly 32 bytes.
Therefore, its length is always 32.
It is unaware of whether it contains a string, number or something else.

I would recommend doing:

```
require(_name[0] != 0);
```

to verify that it does not represent an empty string.

Comment: Note: This only works for null-terminated strings.

Comment: Woudn't that return "false" is _name = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" since _name[0] = "0x00"? wouldn't it be better to do "require(_name > 0)" ?

Comment: If it's a null-terminated string and the first byte is `0x00` then the length of the string is 0 regardless of the content of the other bytes.

Comment: are hex numbers big endian in Solidity @AlbertoMolina?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it like this:

require(_name != bytes32(0));

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above are completely wrong!
You can compare bytes32 and an empty string!

```
require(_name != "");
```